# How to implement quote::ToTokens for an enum?

Tags: enums, rust, quote

I am implementing a procedural macro and I need to provide my own structures to the outside. I need to implement `quote::ToTokens` trait for my structures, but I don't understand how. I have tried this code but did not succeed. This code is compilable, but it is not valid:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Clone)]
pub enum Enum {
    A,
    B,
}
impl quote::ToTokens for Enum {
    fn to_tokens(&self, tokens: &mut quote::Tokens) {
        tokens.append("Enum::B");
    }
}
```

The [`quote::ToTokens` example](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/quote/trait.ToTokens.html) does not explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
impl quote::ToTokens for Enum {
    fn to_tokens(&self, tokens: &mut quote::Tokens) {
        tokens.append("Enum");
        tokens.append("::");
        match *self {
           Enum::A => tokens.append("A"),
           Enum::B => tokens.append("B")
        }
    }
}
```

If you are concerned with how the enum has been imported, then you should re-import it to make sure it is not conflicting with anything else:

```
impl quote::ToTokens for Enum {
    fn to_tokens(&self, tokens: &mut quote::Tokens) {
        tokens.append("{");
        tokens.append("use");
        tokens.append_separated(&["module_name", "Enum"], "::");
        tokens.append(";");
        tokens.append("Enum");
        tokens.append("::");
        match *self {
           Enum::A => tokens.append("A"),
           Enum::B => tokens.append("B")
        }
        tokens.append("}");
    }
}
```

Which will produce:

```
 { use module_name::Enum; Enum::A }
```

Comment: What if we have "use Enum as E;" in our code or we did not even provided `use` for it so it must be prepended with "cratename::" ? Personally I think there must be a method of getting `fully qualified name` for the requested item. P.S. My question implies that your code in your answer is incorrect too :)

Comment: Probably you should always use the fully qualified name, including crate, just to be safe. It's quite ugly though. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You can `use` it once inside the function, then you would only need to FQN it in the impl and in the `use` itself.

Comment: This answer is out of date. `tokens.append(&str)` no longer works.

Comment: @FordO. what is the alternative now? just ran into this issue

Comment: I'm also running into this. I think we're now supposed to use [`quote::TokenStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/quote/latest/quote/trait.TokenStreamExt.html) ("TokenStream extension trait with methods for appending tokens") but I haven't made it work, I get: "the trait cannot be made into an object because method `append` has generic type parameters"